PHP if statement for selected days of the week
I am amending a basic script, but as I'm not a coder, I'm not sure if I have this right :
if (date('l') == 'Monday'){echo "Today is Monday";}
elseif (date('l') == 'Tuesday' || 'Wednesday'){echo "Today is either Tuesday or Wednesday";}
elseif (date('l') == 'Thursday'){echo "Today is Thursday";}
elseif (date('l') == 'Friday'){echo "Today Friday";}
elseif (date('l') == 'Saturday' || 'Sunday'){echo "Today is the weekend";}

Does this look correct ?   It seems that when I change the days of the week around with today's day (swapping Monday with Friday) - I still always only ever get the same result ("Today is Monday").

"Does this look correct ?" It doesn't. 'Wednesday' should be date('l') == 'Wednesday', 'Sunday' should be date('l') == 'Sunday'

The line:
elseif (date('l') == 'Tuesday' || 'Wednesday')

and
elseif (date('l') == 'Saturday' || 'Sunday')

will always be "right", because you need to provide again a name of variable.
so in case of it you need to do something like:
elseif (date('l') == 'Tuesday' || date('l') == 'Wednesday')

So corrected version with better formatting:
if (date('l') == 'Monday') {
    echo "Today is Monday";
} elseif (date('l') == 'Tuesday' || date('l') == 'Wednesday') {
    echo "Today is either Tuesday or Wednesday";
} elseif (date('l') == 'Thursday') {
    echo "Today is Thursday";
} elseif (date('l') == 'Friday') {
    echo "Today is Friday";
} elseif (date('l') == 'Saturday' || date('l') == 'Sunday') {
    echo "Today is the weekend";
}


Hi Kalview, thanks so much !  I've tested that code and it works.  I figured it was something minor I was missing, but didn't know what.   Appreciate your help.
